# performance tuning small T-SQL IF ELSE STATEment, run thousands of times

Tags: performance, t-sql, if-statement

am trying to squeeze some performance out of this query, any help would be appreciated, the only thing I can do is drop the order by on the second statement as it is ordered by primary key

```
--SET STATISTICS TIME ON

DECLARE             
        @MasterAdGroupId Int = 3469476,
        @IncludeDeleted Bit = 1,
        @Deleted Bit = 0,
        @IncludeDirty Bit= 0,
        @Dirty Bit =1,
        @IncludeDupes Bit=0,
        @OrderByText Bit= 1,
        @UseInDisplayNetworkOnly Bit=0

BEGIN

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
IF @OrderByText=1 
BEGIN
    SELECT MasterKeywordId, Text, URL, MasterAdGroupId, mk.KeywordTemplateId, Dirty, mk.Deleted, Negative, Duplicate  
      FROM admanMasterKeyword_tbl mk
INNER JOIN admanKeywordTemplate_tbl kt on kt.KeywordTemplateId = mk.KeywordTemplateId
     WHERE MasterAdGroupId = @MasterAdGroupId 
       AND mk.Deleted = CASE WHEN @IncludeDeleted=0 THEN @Deleted ELSE mk.Deleted END
       AND Dirty = CASE WHEN @IncludeDirty=0 THEN @Dirty ELSE Dirty END
       AND Duplicate = CASE WHEN @IncludeDupes=1 THEN Duplicate ELSE 0 END
       AND UseInDisplayNetwork = CASE WHEN @UseInDisplayNetworkOnly=1 THEN 1 ELSE UseInDisplayNetwork END
  ORDER BY Text 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT MasterKeywordId, Text, URL, MasterAdGroupId, mk.KeywordTemplateId, Dirty, mk.Deleted, Negative, Duplicate  
      FROM admanMasterKeyword_tbl mk
INNER JOIN admanKeywordTemplate_tbl kt on kt.KeywordTemplateId = mk.KeywordTemplateId
     WHERE MasterAdGroupId = @MasterAdGroupId 
       AND mk.Deleted = CASE WHEN @IncludeDeleted=0 THEN @Deleted ELSE mk.Deleted END
       AND Dirty = CASE WHEN @IncludeDirty=0 THEN @Dirty ELSE Dirty END
       AND Duplicate = CASE WHEN @IncludeDupes=1 THEN Duplicate ELSE 0 END
       AND UseInDisplayNetwork = CASE WHEN @UseInDisplayNetworkOnly=1 THEN 1 ELSE UseInDisplayNetwork END
  ORDER BY MasterKeywordId 
END

END
```

Comment: There is no implied order by the primary key, just whatever order the data comes back in. To tune this type of query, I would refer to Erland Sommarskog's definitive article on dynamic search parameters: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to change anything performance wise, but if all you're changing in the two queries is how they are ordered (I couldn't see any differences), you could put a CASE statement right in the ORDER BY and not have to repeat yourself or do an IF statement at all:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 

    SELECT MasterKeywordId, Text, URL, MasterAdGroupId, mk.KeywordTemplateId, Dirty, mk.Deleted, Negative, Duplicate  
      FROM admanMasterKeyword_tbl mk
INNER JOIN admanKeywordTemplate_tbl kt on kt.KeywordTemplateId = mk.KeywordTemplateId
     WHERE MasterAdGroupId = @MasterAdGroupId 
       AND mk.Deleted = CASE WHEN @IncludeDeleted=0 THEN @Deleted ELSE mk.Deleted END
       AND Dirty = CASE WHEN @IncludeDirty=0 THEN @Dirty ELSE Dirty END
       AND Duplicate = CASE WHEN @IncludeDupes=1 THEN Duplicate ELSE 0 END
       AND UseInDisplayNetwork = CASE WHEN @UseInDisplayNetworkOnly=1 THEN 1 ELSE UseInDisplayNetwork END
  ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @OrderByText = 1 THEN Text ELSE MasterKeywordId END)
```

What does the query plan look like for this query? Anywhere you could create indices?

Comment: the query plan is a clustered indexed seek joined with another index seek via a nested loop so it looks ok

Comment: your code definately looks cleaner, so i'll a look if does anything when in the office tomorrow, thanks